# How to Replace Firmware/Software on Motorola SURFboard SBG6580

Tags: firmware, cable-modem

I have a Motorola SURFboard SBG6580 Cable Modem/Router combo that was working great until I upgraded my Internet speed with Comcast at which time, they pushed either a firmware or software update that appears to have caused my modem to stop locking channels with Comcast, making it unusable.

The Comcast technician suggested that this was the case given the timing and knowledge that they push updates to cable modems.

I'd like to get the modem working again and wanted to find out if there is a way to remove any software updates or revert the firmware on the modem.  I've searched online but haven't found anything helpful.  I've reset the modem to factory defaults but that didn't fix the issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does Comcast suggest?  They should be able to push an earlier version.  You may not get the speed they suggested the update would give but your speed is not that great now :-(

Comment: Comcast suggests tossing my modem and renting their modem at $7/month.

Comment: I have a similar situation, where I switched from Verizon FiOS to Comcast, bought a Motorola SBG6580 and could never get it working. As soon as they installed their own gateway (Arris), it worked. So I thought it might be a hardware problem with that individual gateway. So I bought another, but same problem. I'm having a Comcast technician come out *again* tomorrow. Btw, the rental fee is now $8/month. :(

Comment: Probably way too late for you, but I have a similar issue with my SB6121 (Time Warner Cable though), and the on-site technicaian said if the problem continued, he could get a higher-up to stop by, and give a new modem while waiving the leasing fee. See if Comcast can do the same for you, if your own modem is giving fits.